# error when install apc

Tags: php, pecl

i got an error when trying to install apc in xampp (windows).

```
c:\xampp\php>pecl install apc
downloading APC-3.1.9.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.9.tgz (155,540 bytes)
.................................done: 155,540 bytes
54 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin C:\xampp\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php.exe, but con
fig variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP APC.dsp does not exist.

c:\xampp\php>
```

help me please how to get apc.dsp.. thx.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437737/install-apc-on-windows

Comment: i have follow that answer before.. i download the php_apc.dll and put it in /ext after that add some line of code in php.ini.. but it still cannot install apc in my local server. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its windows I guess (from c:\xampp\php). So pecl would not work as it compiles the extension and for it needs, a c compiler, php headers and other stuff.

The easiest way is to download a prebuilt dll and add it to your extensions dir. I have also installed xampp on my win dev machine and done the same thing.

Grab the appropriate dll from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/
For PHP 5.3  [php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip)

DO NOT GET the nts version

If you have the latest version of XAMPP you would need the PHP 5.3 one

extract the dll to c:\xampp\php\ext directory
then add following line to your php.ini which is under c:\xampp\php

```
extension=php_apc.dll
```

**Note:** This workd fine with XAMPP 1.7.4, but does not work with XAMPP 1.7.3 . There is a bundled php_apc.dll (version 3.1.3p) which works just fine. SO which XAMPP version do you have ? (you get the version when you open localhost in your browser

Comment: thx.. ur help is very useful.. :D

Comment: I unable to find php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip file.it takes me to 404

Comment: @gowri it seems Pierre is only hosting the latest version now which is built on VC9, which wont be compatible with old versions of XAMPP (before 1.7.7) which has PHP built from VC6. So for now I'd say either try to use the latest `php_apc-3.1.10-5.3-vc9-x86.zip` from the downloads page and see if it works or stick with the one provided with XAMPP